# How to add a input field in admin grid and post it using mass action- Admin Panel

Tags: grid, admin-panel, adminform, order-grid, custom-admin-grid

**The question is how to get the input data in mass action.**

I have currently added a input field in the admin grid. Like this:

[image: Admin Grid with input field]

I have added the input field using the block. I want to post that values when clicking the mass action. Currently only the entity_id is being posted when I click the massaction button.
I get the values in the controller, for the order data I use collection factory to get the data by using the entity_id. But I cannot get any other post data.

I am sharing my code for this process, correct me if I have to change somewhere or to add anything in it.

***xxxxxx/BulkRefund/Block/Adminhtml/Grid/Grid.php***

```
class Grid extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended
{

   
    protected $_status;

    protected $_blogFactory;

    protected $moduleManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper,
        \xxxxxx\BulkRefund\Model\BulkRefundFactory $blogFactory,
       
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_blogFactory = $blogFactory;
        //$this->_status = $status;
        $this->_formFactory = $formFactory;
        $this->moduleManager = $moduleManager;
        parent::__construct($context, $backendHelper, $data);
    }

    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setId('gridGrid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('entity_id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
        $this->setVarNameFilter('grid_record');
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->_blogFactory->create()->getCollection();
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        parent::_prepareCollection();
        return $this;
    }
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create(
            [
                'data' => [
                    'id'      => 'bulk_refunds',
                    'method'  => 'post',
                    'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
                ],
            ]
        );
        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {

        $this->addColumn(
            'entity_id',
            [
                'header' => __('Entity ID'),
                'type' => 'number',
                'index' => 'entity_id',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-id',
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'increment_id',
            [
                'header' => __('Increment ID'),
                'index' => 'increment_id',
            ]
        );

        

        $this->addColumn(
            'customer_name',
            [
                'header' => __('Customer Name'),
                'index' => 'customer_name'
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'customer_email',
            [
                'header' => __('customer Email'),
                'index' => 'customer_email',
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'created_at',
            [
                'header' => __('Created At'),
                'index' => 'created_at',
            ]
        );


        $this->addColumn(
            'grand_total',
            [
                'header' => __('Grand Total'),
                'index' => 'grand_total',
            ]
        );



        $this->addColumn(
            'total_refunded',
            [
                'header' => __('Total Refunded'),
                'index' => 'total_refunded',
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'qty',
            [
                'filter' => false,
                'sortable' => false,
                'header' => __('Refund Percentage'),
                // 'renderer' => \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Search\Grid\Renderer\Qty::class,
                'renderer' => \xxxxxxx\BulkRefund\Block\Adminhtml\Renderer\RefundAmount::class,
                'name' => 'refund',
                'inline_css' => 'refund',
                'type' => 'input',
                'validate_class' => 'validate-number',
                'method' => 'POST',
                'action' => $this->getUrl('grid/*/massRefund')
                // 'form-method' => 'post',
                // 'method' => 'post'
                //'index' => 'qty'

            ]
        );


        $block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('grid.bottom.links');

        if ($block) {
            $this->setChild('grid.bottom.links', $block);
        }

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }


    protected function _prepareMassaction()
    {
        $this->setMassactionIdField('entity_id');
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('qty');

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem(
            'refund',
            [
                'label' => __('Mass Refund'),
                'url' => $this->getUrl('grid/*/massRefund'),
                'confirm' => __('Are you sure?'),
                // 'getter'    => 'getCustomerName',
                'method' => 'get'
            ]
        );
        return $this;
    }

   
    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('grid/*/grid', ['_current' => true]);
    }


   
}
```

***xxxx/BulkRefund/Block/Adminhtml/Renderer/RefundAmount.php***

```
use Magento\Backend\Block\Context;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\AbstractRenderer;
use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
// use Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\ModuleHistory\CollectionFactory;

class RefundAmount extends AbstractRenderer
{
    private $_storeManager;
    private $imageHelper;
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Image $imageHelper,
        StoreManagerInterface $storemanager,
        // CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_storeManager = $storemanager;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_authorization = $context->getAuthorization();
        $this->imageHelper = $imageHelper;
    }

    public function render(DataObject $row)
    {
      
      
        $qty = $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());
        $qty *= 1;
        if (!$qty) {
            $qty = '';
        }

        // Compose html
        $html = '<form method="post" action="' . $this->getUrl('grid/*/massRefund') .'" id="form-qty-refund" > <input type="text" ';
        $html .= 'name="' . $this->getColumn()->getId() . '" ';
       // $html .= 'value="' . $qty . '"';
        $html .= 'class="input-text admin__control-text ' 
                . $this->getColumn()->getInlineCss() . '" />
                </form>';
        return $html;
       
    }
}
```

***xxxx/BulkRefund/Block/Adminhtml/Grid.php***

```
class Grid extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Container
{

    protected $_template = 'grid/view.phtml';

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->setId('blk_refunds');
        $this->setDestElementId('bulk_refunds');
        $this->setTitle(__('Bulk Refunds'));
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {

        $this->setChild('grid', $this->getLayout()->createBlock('xxxxx\BulkRefund\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Grid', 'grid.view.grid'));
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    protected function _getAddButtonOptions()
    {

        $splitButtonOptions[] = [
            'label' => __('Add New'),
            'onclick' => "setLocation('" . $this->_getCreateUrl() . "')",
        ];
        return $splitButtonOptions;
    }

    protected function _getCreateUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('grid/*/new');
    }

    public function getGridHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('grid');
    }
}
```

***xxxx/BulkRefund/Controller/Adminhtml/Grid/Grid.php***

```
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory;

class Grid extends Action
{

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Rawfactory $resultRawFactory,
        LayoutFactory $layoutFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultRawFactory = $resultRawFactory;
        $this->layoutFactory = $layoutFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $resultRaw = $this->resultRawFactory->create();
        $blogHtml = $this->layoutFactory->create()->createBlock(
            'xxxx\BulkRefund\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Grid',
            'grid.view.grid'
        )->toHtml();
        return $resultRaw->setContents($blogHtml);
    }
}
```

***xxxxx/BulkRefund/Controller/Adminhtml/Grid/MassRefund.php***

```
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;
use xxxxx\BulkRefund\Model\ResourceModel\BulkRefund\CollectionFactory;

class MassRefund extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

    protected $filter;

    protected $collectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Filter $filter,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        \xxxx\BulkRefund\Model\BulkRefundFactory $blogFactory
    ) {
        $this->filter = $filter;
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->_blogFactory = $blogFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $deleteIds = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        print_r($deleteIds); // prints only entity id
        echo "<br>";
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('qty');
        $items = $this->collectionFactory->create()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', $id)->getItems();
       
        foreach ($items as $item) {
           
            print_r($item->getData());

            $test = $item->getData();
            echo "<br>";
            echo $test['increment_id'];
           

        }

        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
    }
}
```

***xxxx/BulkRefund/view/adminhtml/templates/grid/view.phtml***

```
<?php

echo $block->getGridHtml(); 

?>
```

HOPE SOMEONE WILL ANSWER THIS QUESTION

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I Also need to post extra data to a massaction

Comment: Sadly NO! :( @KevinChavez